# AdMob consent form not showing up?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I don't understand why the Google-rendered consent form is not showing up. It says that it loads successfully, but then it doesn't show up. (I am in Europe, so my location is not a problem). I have tried both on simulators and real devices, I have manually selected only 12 ad providers.

Here is the code in question:

```
PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.debugIdentifiers = ["4FDF7D7F-8F56-4E65-8570-103100943386"]
PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.debugGeography = PACDebugGeography.EEA


    PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(forPublisherIdentifiers: ["pub-5765803665103285"]){

        (_ error: Error?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            // Consent info update failed.
            print(error)
        } else {
            // Consent info update succeeded. The shared PACConsentInformation
            // instance has been updated.

            if PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus == PACConsentStatus.unknown {

                guard let privacyUrl = URL(string: "http://www.gdgapps.altervista.org/index.html/gdg-privacy.html"),
                    let form = PACConsentForm(applicationPrivacyPolicyURL: privacyUrl) else {
                        print("incorrect privacy URL.")
                        return
                }
                form.shouldOfferPersonalizedAds = true
                form.shouldOfferNonPersonalizedAds = true
                form.shouldOfferAdFree = true

                form.load {(_ error: Error?) -> Void in
                    print("Load complete.")
                    if let error = error {
                        // Handle error.
                        print("Error loading form: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {

                        print("Load successful.")
                    }
                }

                form.present(from: self) { (error, userPrefersAdFree) in

                    if error != nil {
                        // Handle error.
                    } else if userPrefersAdFree {
                        // User prefers to use a paid version of the app.

                        //TODO: buy pro version
                    } else {
                        // Check the user's consent choice.
                        let status = PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus

                        // TODO: show ads
                    }
                }
            } else if PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus == PACConsentStatus.nonPersonalized || PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus == PACConsentStatus.personalized{

                print("ads")

                self.bannerView.isHidden = false
                self.tableBasso.constant = 50
                self.bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-5765803665103285/9440944250"
                self.bannerView.rootViewController = self

                let request = GADRequest()

                if PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus == PACConsentStatus.nonPersonalized {

                    let extras = GADExtras()
                    extras.additionalParameters = ["npa": "1"]
                    request.register(extras)
                }

                self.bannerView.load(request)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should present the form **after** it's loaded. Put `form.present` inside the completion block of `form.load`.

```
form.load { [weak self] error in
    print("Load complete.")
    if let error = error {
        print("Error loading form: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        form.present(from: strongSelf) { error, userPrefersAdFree in
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```