# I am unable to load the Google AdMob gdpr consent form with my code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gdprconsentform

I have followed google instructions https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/eu-consent#objective-c on how to implement it and came up with this code:
I am using Xcode version 11.5 and get no errors in the code the form just doesn't show.

```
#import "boogagoogleform.h"
#import <PersonalizedAdConsent/PersonalizedAdConsent.h>

@interface boogagoogleform ()

@end

@implementation boogagoogleform

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // TODO: Replace with your app's privacy policy url.
    NSURL *privacyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.your.com/privacyurl"];
    PACConsentForm *form = [[PACConsentForm alloc] initWithApplicationPrivacyPolicyURL:privacyURL];
    form.shouldOfferPersonalizedAds = YES;
    form.shouldOfferNonPersonalizedAds = YES;
    form.shouldOfferAdFree = FALSE;
    [form loadWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
      NSLog(@"Load complete. Error: %@", error);
      if (error) {
        // Handle error.
      } else {
        // Load successful.
      }
    }];
    [form presentFromViewController:self
        dismissCompletion:^(NSError *_Nullable error, BOOL userPrefersAdFree) {
          if (error) {
            // Handle error.
          } else if (userPrefersAdFree) {
            // The user prefers to use a paid version of the app.
          } else {
            // Check the user's consent choice.
            PACConsentStatus status =
                PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus;
          }
        }];
    [PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance
        requestConsentInfoUpdateForPublisherIdentifiers:@[ @"pub-012345678" ]
            completionHandler:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
              if (error) {
                // Consent info update failed.
              } else {
                // Consent info update succeeded. The shared PACConsentInformation
                // instance has been updated.
              }
            }];

    PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus = PACConsentStatusPersonalized;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AdMob consent form not showing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427003/admob-consent-form-not-showing-up)

Comment: Tried his code with some changes didn't work. Still no errors in code just doesn't show